# If/Else: Adding "Or" to the If statement

Tags: php

I'm trying to condense my code to create less lines of PHP and was wondering if this is possible.  Currently I have:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']==domain1.com" ) {
    down();
} elseif ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="domain2.com" ) {
    down();
} else {
    up();
}
?>
```

instead of having `if` and `elseif` displaying the same function, is it possible to do something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']==domain1.com" || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="domain2.com" ) {
    down();
} else {
    up();
}
?>
```

I tried the code above but my page went blank.. how do I do this if possible?

Comment: Step 1: fix syntax errors.

Comment: Just missed quotes (").

Comment: You're missing an " in the line $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']==domain1.com"

Comment: if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="domain1.com"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of the syntax errors -

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="domain1.com" || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="domain2.com" ) {
    down();
} else {
    up();
}
```

or you can do this also -

```
$domains = array("domain1.com", "domain2.com");
if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $domains)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Shorter way:

```
$domains = ["domain1.com", "domain2.com"];
in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $domains) ? down() : up();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the opening " for the first $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']==domain1.com"

try with :

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="domain1.com" || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="domain2.com" ) {
    down();
} else {
    up();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Fix syntax errors please

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="domain1.com" || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="domain2.com" ) {
    down();
} else {
    up();
}
?>
```